# How to remove shadow from text area border

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create text area with black borders.

```
TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();
dataPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-radius: 16;");
```

But I get this result:

[image]

Can you tell me how I can remove this blue shadow?

Comment: inspect it using chrome you will find -webkit or -moz values are set you need to override those using ur reset css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blue border is not a shadow but a default focus color in caspian style of JavaFX for controls. You can see its definition in *caspian.css* as `-fx-focus-color` with default value `#0093ff`.

Now we can override this color palette per control. So you do

```
dataPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1; "
                + "-fx-border-radius: 16; -fx-focus-color: transparent");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to completely remove all the borders, shadows, highlights:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-text-fill: gray;
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}
```